# C++ call of overloaded constructor is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default, constructor-overloading

Let's say I have this dummy class definition:

```
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node ();
        Node (const int = 0);
        int getVal();
    private:
        int val;
    };
```

And dummy constructor implementations for educational purposes only as well:

```
Node::Node () : val(-1)
{
    cout << "Node:: DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR" << endl;
}


Node::Node(const int v) : val(v) 
{
    cout << "Node:: CONV CONSTRUCTOR val=" << v << endl;
}
```

**Now**, if I compile (with options: `-Wall -Weffc++ -std=c++11`) the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    Node n;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error, and does not compile at all:

```
node_client.CPP: In function ‘int main()’:
node_client.CPP:10:16: error: call of overloaded ‘Node()’ is ambiguous
  Node n;  
                ^
node_client.CPP:10:16: note: candidates are:
In file included from node_client.CPP:4:0:
node.h:14:5: note: Node::Node(int)
     Node (const int = 0);     
     ^
node.h:13:2: note: Node::Node()
  Node ();
  ^
```

I cannot understand why.

As far as I know (I am learning C++), a call to `Node::Node()` should not be ambiguous with respect to `Node::Node(const int)` because the have a different parameter signature.

There is something I am missing: What it is?

Comment: Hint: look at the default value in the second constructor.

Comment: Sure, it's true. Thanks :).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> a call to Node::Node() should not be ambiguous with respect to Node::Node(const int) because the have a different parameter signature.

Sure that is ambiguous. Think twice!

You have

```
    Node ();
    Node (const int = 0);
```

which one should be selected when you call `Node()`?? The one with the defaulted value parameter?

It should work without providing the default:

```
    Node ();
    Node (const int); // <<<<<<<<<<<<< No default
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler just cannot know if you want to call the default constructor or the `int` constructor with a default value.

You have to remove the default value or remove the default constructor (which does the same thing as your constructor with `int` so that's not really a problem!)